# How to fix "error APPX0002: Task 'ValidateAppxManifest' failed" error when running an MsBuild.exe command as a service?

Tags: tfs, uwp, msbuild, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I try to run an MSBuild command to package an UWP application from an azure TFS build step.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\TFSagent\_work\1\s\MyProject.sln" /t:Build /p:Configuration=master /p:Platform=x86"
```

This command execute well when i log onto the remote VM agent and i just execute the command: package is created just fine as expected.

But when the command is executed via TFS Agent that runs as a service i got the following error :

```
2019-06-16T22:15:16.0141845Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2638,5): error APPX0002: Task 'ValidateAppxManifest' failed. Namespace prefix 'm' is not defined. [C:\TFSagent\_work\1\s\MyProject.vcxproj]
2019-06-16T22:15:16.0142853Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2638,5): error APPX0002:  [C:\TFSagent\_work\1\s\MyProject.vcxproj]
2019-06-16T22:15:16.9689847Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2638,5): error MSB4018: The "ValidateAppxManifest" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\TFSagent\_work\1\s\MyProject.vcxproj]
2019-06-16T22:15:16.9690436Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2638,5): error MSB4018: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Namespace prefix 'm' is not defined. [C:\TFSagent\_work\1\s\MyProject.vcxproj]
...
```

Running: Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 16.131.28507.4

Agent is setup as a service, on a windows 10 vm, using a local user, that is granted administrator rights.

Build Step is as simple as a command-line executing te above command.
I've tried adding `/nodeReuse:false /m:1`.

There is no use of any 'm' namespace in the corresponding manifest (and as it works when runnning 'by hand' i suppose the manifest itself is fine)

I just expect the command to work the same when running from a user or a service.

#### EDIT 1:

i may have found where the 'm' namespace comes from (when using `/v:diag`:

```
Task Parameter:
      AppxManifestSchemas=
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\Include\10.0.18362.0\WinRT\FoundationManifestSchema.xsd
                  NamespaceAlias=m
                  NamespaceUri=http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\Include\10.0.18362.0\WinRT\UapManifestSchema.xsd
                  NamespaceAlias=uap
                  NamespaceUri=http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10 (TaskId:271)
```

#### EDIT 2

in the non working msbuild diag log, the parameter AppxManifestSchemas does not appear at all, probably explaining the intial error.
next step : finding why the parameter is not send to the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​Solution found!
​
​I had a Variable in my Build Definition named "SdkVersion" which was used to control the target sdk i wanted to build on.
​This variable was used in my command line only.

Thing is, TFS is creating an environment variable for each variable in the build configuration.
​
​During the MsBuild PRocess, and specifically task 'GetSdkPropertyValue' (task which is a dependecy for ValidateAppxManifest', which apparently add some AppxManifestSchema, including one with NamespaceAlias=m )​

, there is a parameter named 'SDKVERSION' .. by default (when running manually) it takes the value '10.0' but as i had a variable with same name, it was overidde with '10.0.18362.0' which leads to adding no appxmanifestschema...
​
​Took me a month :p